# What's the keyboard shortcuts to open a list in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

In Twitter, I can use <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open my lists, and use <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> to move up/down the lists. But what is the keyboard shortcut to open the highlighted list?

I tried to look up the help message by pressing <kbd>?</kbd>, but I did not find the appropriate shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It's not documented anywhere, but it works for me.

Comment: Sadly, this trick does not work for me.. (Mac Chrome)